# Remove a Pester mocked function

Tags: powershell, mocking, pester

How is it possible to `unmock` a previously mocked function? Sometimes I find myself in a situation that I want to test a function that I previously `mocked`.

**A simplified example:**

```bsh
Describe 'Pester mocking' {
    $testFile = Join-Path  $env:TEMP 'test.txt'

    It 'should be green' {
        Mock Out-File

        'Text' | Out-File -FilePath $testFile

        Assert-MockCalled Out-File -Times 1 -Exactly
    }
    It 'should be green' {
        # Unmock Out-File

        'Text' | Out-File -FilePath $testFile

        $testFile | Should -Exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, it appears that `Pester` creates an `alias` for each mocked function. The solution would be to remove the `alias` from the scope. This way the real `CmdLet` will be called.

There are two ways of doing this depending on your version of `PowerShell`:

```bsh
Remove-Item Alias:\Out-File
Remove-Alias Out-File
```

**Solution:**

```bsh
Describe 'Pester mocking' {
    $testFile = Join-Path  $env:TEMP 'test.txt'

    It 'should be green' {
        Mock Out-File

        'Text' | Out-File -FilePath $testFile

        Assert-MockCalled Out-File -Times 1 -Exactly
    }
    It 'should be green' {
        Remove-Item Alias:\Out-File

        'Text' | Out-File -FilePath $testFile

        $testFile | Should -Exist
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be good to get confirmation from the Pester people that this is a supported thing to do.